# PopupContainerEdit with XtraTreeList as dropdown Demo

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I am looking for a tuorial on how to add an XtraTreeList as popup control in PopupContainerEdit. Or any working tutorial on how to add control in PopupContainerEdit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please refer to the

[PopupContainerEdit class](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsPopupContainerEdittopic)

topic in this regard.  Also, here is some sample code:

```
PopupContainerEdit edit = new PopupContainerEdit();
        Controls.Add(edit);
        PopupContainerControl pControl = new PopupContainerControl();
        Controls.Add(pControl);
        TreeList tl = new TreeList();
        tl.Columns.Add().Visible = true;
        tl.AppendNode(new object[] { "123" }, null);
        pControl.Controls.Add(tl);
        edit.Properties.PopupControl = pControl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a `PopupContainerControl`, put something inside of it, and set it to the `PopupContainerEdit`'s `PopupControl` property.

Comment: I am kinda new to these things. Any tutorial ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`PopupContainerControl`](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsPopupContainerControltopic) like SLaks's said.

Also you can find a lot of example in [`Devexpress Tv`](http://tv.devexpress.com/) and [`Devexpress Demo`](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Demos.xml)